# Regex to match words followed by whitespace or punctuation

Tags: python, regex

If I have the word `india`

MATCHES
`"india!" "india!" "india." "india"`

NON MATCHES `"indian" "indiana"`

Basically, I want to match the string but not when its contained within another string.

After doing some research, I started with

`exp = "(?<!\S)india(?!\S)" 
num_matches = len(re.findall(exp))`

but that doesn't match the punctuation and I'm not sure where to add that in.

Comment: post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: ah sorry I posted it before but didn't realize some of it was cut off

Comment: `re.findall(r"(india)[\s\.,?!;]", "indiana, indian, india!india. india") ===>
['india', 'india']`

Comment: You're question does not tell us if you wish to match `india` in the string `*india9`, or in many other strings. Moreover, "Basically, I want to match the string but not when its contained within another string." is meaningless. Rather than framing your question in terms of examples you need to begin by stating your question precisely in words. Here's an example of one possible interpretation: "I wish to match a given word in a string provided the word is neither preceded nor followed by a character that is not in the string `" .,?!;"`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objective is to match a given word (e.g., `"india"`) in a string provided the word is neither preceded nor followed by a character that is not in the string `" .,?!;"` you could use the following regex:

```
(?<![^ .,?!;])india(?![^ .,?!;\r\n])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8yVOIt/1/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations

```
(?<!             # begin a negative lookbehind
  [^ .,?!;]      # match 1 char other than those in " .,?!;"
)                # end the negative lookbehind
india            # match string
(?!              # begin a negative lookahead   
  [^ .,?!;\r\n]  # match 1 char other than those in " .,?!;\r\n"
)                # end the negative lookahead
```

Notice that the character class in the negative lookahead contains `\r` and `\n` in case `india` is at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
r'\bindia\W*\b'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EidmoK/2)

---

To ignore case:

```
re.search(r'\bindia\W*\b', my_string, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use:

```
import re

s = "india."
s1 = "indiana"
print(re.search(r'\bindia[.!?]*\b', s))
print(re.search(r'\bindia[.!?]*\b', s1))
```

output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='india'>
None
```

Comment: I ran this in my python3 terminal and I'm getting matches for both -> 
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='india!'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='india'>

Comment: @sy89 check now

Answer (score 1):

```
\"india(\W*?)\"
```

this will catch anything except for numbers and letters

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`^india[^a-zA-Z0-9]$`

`^` - Regex starts with India

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` - not a-z, A-Z, 0-9

`$` - End Regex

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to match the punctuation, you could use make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) where you could match any char except a word character or a newline.

```
(?<!\S)india[^\w\r\n]*(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace bounadry to the left
- `india` Match literally
- `[^\w\r\n]` Match 0+ times any char except a word char or a newline
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VdEps1/1)

Comment: #4, the OP’s expression for `exp` suggests to me that he/she is not trying to match double-quotes, that the double-quotes are merely used in defining strings labelled “MATCHES” and “NON-MATCHES”. That is, the string `”india”` is comprised of five letters.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Reading the question again I think you are right :-) Apparently I was really focused on all the double quotes.

Comment: I have a similar learning disability, misreading questions to make them more interesting.